# Owin.Security.Providers - OpenIDAuthenticationMiddlewareBase derived class claims a FieldNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin-middleware, owin.security

Using Nuget packages `Owin.Security.Providers.OpenIDBase 2.1.1` and `Owin.Security.Provides.OpenID 2.24.0` - DLLs version `2.0.0.0`.

I'm deriving my own provider - i.e. `MyOwnAuthenticationMiddleware : OpenIDAuthenticationMiddlewareBase<MyOwnAuthenticationOptions>`, and passing that to `IAppBuilder.Use()` as part of the standard Startup.

This compiles and runs fine on my own machine - the classic developer line.

But when built on Microsoft Visual Studio Online's build server (Hosted 2017), it builds but then throws a runtime error on startup:

```
MissingFieldException: Field not found:
    'Owin.Security.Providers.OpenIDBase.OpenIDAuthenticationMiddlewareBase`1.HTTPClient'.]
    xxxx.CreateSpecificHandler()
```

Field `HTTPClient` (a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`) apparently can't be found in the derived generic class -it's a member of `OpenIDAuthenticationMiddlewareBase`, which hasn't changed in living memory.

I was thinking that the build server must be linking to a different `OpenIDAuthenticationMiddlewareBase`, but the full canonical name in the error message indicates otherwise.

I am receiving a fair few warnings due to ongoing .NET Framework/.NET Standard DLL hell - one relates to different versions of `System.Net.Http`, which I have as a Nuget package also. Could this be relevant?

On an unrelated note - does anyone else feel like the combination of Nuget dependencies and the bewildering array of .NET Framework/Standard/Core versioning has just recreated the same DLL hell that .NET was supposed to alleviate in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with System.Net.Http and .NETStandard.

If you have a solution/project targeting .NET Framework 4.6/4.7 that involves referencing .NETStandard2, you may have a bad time. See issues [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/484) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/613) on Github. Keywords: .NET Standard, .NET Framework, ASP.NET, System.Net.Http, MissingMethodException, FieldNotFoundException.

Symptoms: runtime exceptions - such as `FieldNotFoundException`, where the field in question could be a HttpClient, for example, something from the `System.Net.Http` package. Or (in my case also, in the case of BotFramework) - requests to `api/messages`, users trying to talk to the bot fail with a `MissingMethodException`. Which you can only see in server logs or ApplicationInsights. From the user's POV, it fails silently.

The consensus seems to be that an explicit reference to `System.Net.Http` is required in these circumstances. Easiest is to add the a binding redirect to your web.config - for example, for Nuget `System.Net.Http` package version 4.3.3:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The reason this wasn't there in the first place is that I had `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` in my .csproj file, in the mistaken belief that letting the system take care of binding redirects would be best - see the article [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481). However, I missed the bit where it (clearly) says autogenerated binding redirects don't work in web application projects!